# How to resort Material React table rows by using drag and drop in Playwright

Tags: playwright

I am trying to drag and drop a row to resort a Material React table using Playwright with TypeScript, but neither the dragTo() nor the hover()/mouse.down()/hover()/mouse.up() methods are resorting the rows.

This was what I tried using boundingBox, but it also does not work

```
test('testing MUI Draggable table', async ({ page }) => {
  await page.goto('https://www.material-react-table.com/docs/guides/row-ordering-dnd');
  await page.keyboard.press("PageDown");
  await page.keyboard.press("PageDown");
  await page.keyboard.press("PageDown");

  const source = page.locator('.css-1xdn0p8').getByRole('row', {name: "Kohler"}).getByRole('cell').first();
  const target = page.locator('.css-1xdn0p8').getByRole('row', {name: "McCullough"}).getByRole('cell').first();

  const sourceBox = await source.boundingBox();
  const targetBox = await target.boundingBox();

  const sourceX = sourceBox.x + sourceBox.width;
  const sourceY = sourceBox.y + sourceBox.height;

  const targetX = targetBox.x + targetBox.width / 2;
  const targetY = targetBox.y + targetBox.height / 2; 

  await page.mouse.move(sourceX, sourceY, { steps: 5 });
  await page.mouse.down({ button: 'left' });
  await page.mouse.move(targetX, targetY, { steps: 5 });
  await page.mouse.up();
});
```

Comment: Please share a [mcve] with the page under test.

Answer (score 0):

Seems that you should calculate coordinates of source and target points from and to where you want to drag element by mouse + use method mouse.move to drag element.

```
  // calculate coords of center point of source element
  const sourceX = source.x + source.width / 2;
  const sourceY = source.y + source.height / 2; 

  // calculate coords of center point of target element
  const targetX = target.x + target.width / 2;
  const targetY = target.y + target.height / 2; 

  await page.mouse.move(sourceX, sourceY, { steps: 5 });
  await page.mouse.down({ button: 'left' });
  await page.mouse.move(targetX, targetY, { steps: 5 });
  await page.mouse.up();
```

Comment: Thank you for your help!  It pointed me in the right direction.  I had to increase the steps for the second move to 10 and it worked.  Thank you again for your help!  I truly appreciate it!

Answer (score 0):

Here is the code that ended up working for me.  I changed the selectors to be the buttons in the cells, not just the cells themselves, and then I upped the steps to 10.

````
test('testing MUI Draggable table', async ({ page }) => {
  await page.goto('https://www.material-react-table.com/docs/guides/row-ordering-dnd');

  await page.keyboard.press("PageDown");
  await page.keyboard.press("PageDown");
  await page.keyboard.press("PageDown");
  const source = page.locator('.css-1xdn0p8').getByRole('row', {name: "Kohler"}).getByRole('cell').first().getByRole('button');
  const target = page.locator('.css-1xdn0p8').getByRole('row', {name: "McCullough"}).getByRole('cell').first().getByRole('button');

  const sourceBox = await source.boundingBox();
  const targetBox = await target.boundingBox();

  const sourceX = sourceBox.x + sourceBox.width / 2;
  const sourceY = sourceBox.y + sourceBox.height / 2;

  const targetX = targetBox.x + targetBox.width / 2;
  const targetY = targetBox.y + targetBox.height / 2; 
  await page.mouse.move(sourceX, sourceY);
  await page.mouse.down();
  await page.mouse.move(targetX, targetY, { steps: 10 });
  await page.mouse.up();
});```
````